# Iteratively parsing a JSON file with ijson

Tags: python, json, bigdata, ijson

I want to parse a huge json file in chunks. I want to use chunks of it without loading the whole thing. 
The data can be found here 
http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/

When I use ijson to do that I get an error of `JSONError: Additional data`.
Is there any way to do this?

My code:##produces Additional Data Error

```
import pandas as pd


file = open('Books_5.json',"r") ##Books_5.json is the 5-core small dataset
objects = ijson.items(file, 'meta.data.item')
reviews = (o for o in objects if o['type']=='reviewText')
for review in reviews : print(review)
```

This does work, but is very slow:

```
path='Books_5.json'
def parse(path):
  g = open(path, 'rb')
  for l in g:
    yield eval(l)
def getDF(path):
  i = 0
  df = {}
  for d in parse(path):
    df[i] = d
    i += 1
  return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df, orient='index')

df = getDF(path)
df.info()
```

[result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGaet.png)

Comment: Hello there, you question is a bit vague, mate. Are you asking what's the best way of implementation as in theory or rather guidance on editing a piece of working snippet you already made?

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess lazy load is not what I mean. Wrong terminology.

Comment: It's ok, buddy. Make sure to edit your question to ease the way for others to help you out. ;)

Comment: I just want to not download a huge json file with reviews, and a workaround. I'm looking for a link or a snippet.

Comment: >I get an error of json improperly formed
Can you please share the exact error you got?

Comment: user10598282: ijson does iterative json _parsing_ — and has nothing to do with downloading. Perhaps the improperly formed error you were getting was due to trying to parse incomplete json formatted data.

Comment: Yes, I used iterative parsing with requests. Give me a minute

Comment: Here's something that can be of a good help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316427/how-to-send-and-receive-large-json-data
We need the error to help you debug it, but also the code snippet you used to fetch the JSON data.

Comment: Sorry, that was another problem. This file is on my system. I'm editing this post. My apologies.

Comment: I suggest you rry parsing the "small" Books_5.json dataset which you have apprently already downloaded with the regular `json` module and see if it can do so without errors. Doing that should tell you if the problem is due to an improperly formed (or perhaps corrupted) dataset or a bug in the `ijson` module (or how you're using it).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the JSON data has more than one top-level object in it, which is not supported by the JSON standard. However ijson still supports this when using the  `multiple_values=True` option (e.g., `ijson.items(file, 'meta.data.item', multiple_values=True)`.